# How to grab Tkinter inputs and put into config

Tags: python, tkinter, input, config

For example I want to get an input from tkinter and in the GUI it says `"how much do you like cars from 1 - 10?"` and then the victim inputs a number for example `8` how would I transfer my input to my settings.ini?

My Code:

```
root = Tk()
config = ConfigParser()
updater = ConfigUpdater()

path = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
configPath = os.path.join(path, "settings.ini")

updater.read('settings.ini')
updater['Trading Settings']['maximum_value_gain'].value = "the input I want from tkinter user"
updater.update_file()


root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

For your case, you can use `OptionMenu` for the rating input as below:

```
import os
import tkinter as tk
from configupdater import ConfigUpdater

appPath = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
configPath = os.path.join(appPath, "settings.ini")

updater = ConfigUpdater()
updater.read(configPath) # settings.ini must exists, otherwise exception

root = tk.Tk()

tk.Label(root, text='How much do you like cars (from 1 - 10)?').grid(row=0, column=0)

rating = tk.StringVar()
rating_opt = tk.OptionMenu(root, rating, *range(1, 11)) # dropdown with values 1 to 10
rating_opt.config(width=5)
rating_opt.grid(row=0, column=1)

def update():
    value = rating.get()
    # update ini file only when user has selected a rating
    if value:
        updater['Trading Settings']['maximum_value_gain'].value = rating.get()
        updater.update_file()

tk.Button(root, text='Update', command=update).grid(row=2, column=0, columnspan=2)

root.mainloop()
```